# Best practice for using boolean with MySQL and JSON

Tags: mysql, json, boolean

Are there any suggestions on how to best handle the fact that neither MySQL nor JSON have a boolean data type? Right now I'm thinking of always just using 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 1, because that would be at least consistent.

As I see all other possibilities have severe downsides. When I use php to read a MySQL-Record and send it to JavaScript via AJAX in JSON format - I just receive a 0 or 1 there anyway. If I send JSON to php I would receive a string "true" or "false" there - which I would have to query via string in php (also not a nice solution).

My solution of only using 0 and 1 has a downside too, but I consider that a smaller one: When I have a JavaScript function with a bool input that has to be transferred to php I would already have to use 0 and 1 there (which is not nicely readable) - or I would have to translate the values in the function before the JSON encoding. Still I prefer both variants to querying "if (mybool == 'true') in php.

Any suggestions are greately appreciated.

Comment: Both MySQL and JSON support booleans. Well...MySQL makes a good effort at least.

Answer (score 0):

> neither MySQL nor JSON have a boolean data type

JSON does support `boolean` as a type natively.

MySQL provides BOOLEAN or BOOL as the synonym of TINYINT(1). It also provides convenient `TRUE`/`FALSE` constants. So even though MySQL *internally* uses a `TINYINT(1)` to store boolean values, from your point of view that shouldn't matter. You just need to *read* the MySQL value as a boolean, instead of an integer.

> When I have a JavaScript function with a bool input that has to be transfered to php I would already have to use 0 and 1 there

What do you mean by "transfered to php"? If you mean that PHP code will be used on the server to handle an AJAX request, there is no problem. PHP also supports [`boolean`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) natively, so if you send a JSON request containing boolean values, they will be deserialized into a PHP data structure containing booleans as well.

Comment: That is incorrect, JSON does differentiate Boolean T\F from 1\0

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Comment: Well, maybe I'm doing something wrong,  but I'm having two problems:

1. When I use the following jQuery instruction:
$.post('some.php', { 'somebool': true}, function (result) ...

in php this won't work: 
if ($_post['somebool'] == true) 

instead I have to use 
if ($_post['somebool'] == 'true') 

2. Yes, I can set and query "bool" MySQL Fields using true and false. But if I read a MySQL record using mysqli_fetch_array - I suppose the data type of the field will already not be bool any more. And if I pass it back to JavaScript/jQuery I will receive 0 or 1, not true or false.

Comment: @MasonStedman Where did you see me stating otherwise?